# My .NET Core project isn't listening on the secure port when run as a different admin user

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

In my `appsettings.json` I have this Kestrel configuration:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  },
```

When I run the application from Visual Studio OR as myself from the command line, it runs fine and listens on both http 5000 and https 5001 as I expect:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:5000, https://localhost:5001'. 
      Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\git\Company\application\appname\myApp
```

However, when I try to run the application as a different user ("`test`" - with admin permissions) it doesn't listen on https 5001, *and* the `Hosting environment` and `Content root path` are different:

```
runas /user:test .\myApp.exe
```

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' 
      as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
                                              <-- why aren't we listening on https://localhost:5001?
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production         <-- okay...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Windows\system32  <-- something tells me that's not gonna work
```

I need to be able to run the application as any user, and haven't a clue how to fix this.

Comment: In what file exactly the quoted Kestrel config is defined?

Comment: appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, and appsettings.Production.json.  They all have the same values

Comment: You will have to `ELEVATE` user 'test' so he/she actually runs as admin (like you do from VS). or run VS as an unelevated user to compare.